Why NullInjectionError problem not solved by adding ProvideHttpClient() in app.config file of Angular 18
I am trying to fetch data from the backend of my application. The data fetching works well with combination of promise and fetch function. But when I tried to implement it using HttpClient service it gives error. I checked previous response in this platform but couldn't solve the problem.
app.config.ts
import {ApplicationConfig} from '@angular/core';
import { provideHttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [provideHttpClient()],
};

housing.service.ts
export class HousingService {
  url = "http://localhost:5150"
  protected homeLocationList2: HomeLocation[] = [];
  
  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { 
  }


  getAllProduct(): Observable<HomeLocation[]>{
    const response = this.http.get<HomeLocation[]>(`${this.url}/Home/AllProduct`)
    return response 
  }
}

Home.Component.ts
export class HomeComponent {
  productList:HomeLocation[] = [];
  housingService: HousingService = inject(HousingService)


  constructor(){
    this.housingService.getAllProduct().subscribe(data=>{
      this.productList = data;
    })
  }
}

This is the github link of the source code
https://github.com/ishanuzzal/angular_full_stack

Error I get
ERROR NullInjectorError: NullInjectorError: No provider for _HttpClient!
    at NullInjector.get (core.mjs:1632:21)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:3014:27)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:3014:27)
    at injectInjectorOnly (core.mjs:1095:36)
    at Module.ɵɵinject (core.mjs:1101:40)
    at Object.HousingService_Factory [as factory] (housing.service.ts:8:28)
    at core.mjs:3132:35
    at runInInjectorProfilerContext (core.mjs:866:5)
    at R3Injector.hydrate (core.mjs:3131:11)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:3005:23)


That looks right. Are you sure the null injector error is for HttpClient? Can you create and link a StackBlitz that reproduces the error?

Do you have an app.module.ts? In this case, the provideHttpClient() needs to be added to the AppModule.

Please pay attention when adding tags; [tag:angularjs] is used for Angular v1 at https//angularjs.org/ that has been defunct now for 2 years. Angular v18 is covered by the [tag:angular] tag.

I do not have app.module.ts

@SAFIQULISLAMUZZAL203-15-144 please share a github repo for checking, require more details

I suspect on yourbootstrapApplication(), confirm that you are provided your appConfig to it. Can you share it?

https://github.com/ishanuzzal/angular_full_stack

It appears you have created an app.config.ts but you don't use it. Import it in src/main.ts:
import { appConfig } from './app/app.config';

bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, appConfig).catch((err) =>
  console.error(err),
);

Also make sure to add the config that you previously had in main.ts to app.config.ts:
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideHttpClient(),
    provideProtractorTestingSupport(),
    provideRouter(routeConfig),
  ],
};


You are not using app.config.ts (Deleted it), instead add provideHttpClient on the main.ts providers array.
import {bootstrapApplication, provideProtractorTestingSupport} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {AppComponent} from './app/app.component';
import { provideRouter } from '@angular/router';
import { provideHttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

import routeConfig from './app/route';
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {providers: [
  provideProtractorTestingSupport(),
  provideRouter(routeConfig),
  provideHttpClient(), // <- changed here!
]
}).catch((err) =>
  console.error(err),
);

Forked Github Repo
